# How to keep objects in node Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have array of objects with this structure

```
[{
 name:'here is name, which can have  punctuation marks ',
 value: 'here will be text '
},
{
 name:'here is name, which can have  punctuation marks ',
 value: 'here will be text '
}]
```

I am trying to find the best way to keep it in neo4j node. Since later I am going to search, filter ... on this data I don't want to keep hole object as string. Creating property by name object.name is not possible because I have punctuation marks. The ideal way would be to keep it as property, because I am going to use this data as property of node, but removing punctuation marks from name is not an option too.
Probably I could keep them in array

```
['here is the name', ' and the second element of array is the text']
```

In this case the problem will be to give correct name to the property, which will have this array.
Another option could be to keep all data in list like this

```
tabs: ['first name - first value', ' second name - second value']
```

but to search later I will need to use regex inside the list. this doesn't seem flexible.
So what would be the best way ?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use backticks  as mentioned in neo4j community forum by [Andreas Kollegger](https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-keep-objects-in-node/47714/3?u=armensanoyan)

```
CREATE ({`here is "name", which has  punctuation marks!`:"here will be text"})
```

for more complex cases [Giuseppe Villani](https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-keep-objects-in-node/47714/2?u=armensanoyan) suggested better solution

```
CALL apoc.create.nodes(["MyLabel"], [{
 `name.with.dots`:'here is name, which can have  punctuation marks .',
 value: 'here will be text '
},
{
 name:'here is name, which can have  punctuation marks ',
 value: 'here will be text '
}]) yield node
return node
```

to create a Node with a label ("MyLabel" in this case), so that you can have every data you need in a specific label (possibly to be indexed and/or connect with other entities)

Answer (score 0):

You have few possibilities in terms of storing objects in the Neo4j database.

1. You can turn your JSON object into a string and save it as a property and later you can use `APOC procedures` for conversation to/from (using these procedures can help you with filtering or sorting on these).
2. You can create the helper nodes and treat each element of a list as a separate node (I think this is the suggested approach).

Worth to mention, that you can [link your nodes](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/creating-and-working-with-linked-lists/) to keep the order or just connect them directly if you don't really care about order.